# Считывание информации из файла

Tags: java, файлы

Мне необходимо из файла считать в три массива информацию о транспортной задаче.

Например, у меня есть файл, и из него нужно:

В массив `A` считать:

```
14.5 10 15
```

В массив `B`:

```
10 15.7 12
```

И в массив `С` остальную матрицу.

Пример файла:

```
8 12 15 5 80 
6 7 9 12 100
12 5 11 10 50
60 60 70 40
```

Как это лучше сделать? У меня есть две идеи: либо изначально считывать все в один массив, а потом распределять, но это неудобно; либо же сразу разбить по файлам, но я не представляю, как это тогда реализовать на джаве.

Пример разбития на массивы такой:

```
private double[] proposition = {14.5,10,15,12};
private double[] demand = {10,15.7,12,15}; 
private double[][] price = {
            {10,30,25,15},
            {20,15,20,10},
            {10,30,20,20},
            {30,40,35,45}};
```

Кусок кода, который только считывает, но не разбивает на массивы:

```
public class Files {
    String line;

    // построчное считывание файла
    public String read() {
        try {
            File file = new File("ex3.txt");
            // создаем объект FileReader для объекта File
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            // создаем BufferedReader с существующего FileReader
            // для построчного считывания
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            // считаем сначала первую строку
            line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                // считываем остальные строки в цикле
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return line;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Files files = new Files();
        files.read();
    }
}
```

[image: Виды записей в файл]

В первом варианте магазинов (80,100,50) меньше, в другом (80,100,50) больше. Последняя строка -- всегда покупатели, и считываться должна полностью.

Comment: а по какому принципу вы распределяете значения? и почему ваш первый вариант "неудобен"?

Comment: @JVic,  последний столбец матрицы  (14 10 15) --  всегда покупатели, последняя строка (10 15 12) -- всегда магазины. Остальная "квадратная матрица" -- расценки. Неудобно, потому что потом все равно придется разбивать на три массива

Comment: дело в том, что изобретать велосипед, выполняющий чтение из файла каким-то особым образом - еще та радость. это на много больший костыль, чем обработать уже готовые данные

Comment: Добавила вариант считывания в String, чтобы потом разбить по массивах. Но мне нужно разбить на массивы типов float/int, и мне кажется, что это не лучший вариант. Подскажите, если ли что-то более подходящее?

Comment: А что планируется делать с тремя массивами потом? возможно тут подойдет какая то другая структура лучше?

Comment: @JVic, дальше их использую для подсчета минимальных расходов и тд. я написала программу, только данные брала без считывания. Массивы double [][], double [] и double []. Не понимаю совсем, как дальше эти данные записать в массивы

Comment: Приведите в вопросе примеры массивов, с которыми уже работает ваша программа, вот эти вот ваши `double[][], double[], double[]` что в них хранится

Comment: @JVic, добавила примеры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас очень странный подход к решению задачи. Ваши интерфейсы работают с 3 массивами , один из которых двухмерный. Это крайне неудобно с точки зрения реализации дальнейшей бизнесс-логики. Но если это уже реализовано и вам действительно необходимо получит данные в таком виде, то я бы предложил сделать специальный класс, который будет вычитывать из файла и готовить для вас все необходимые данные в виде, с которым работают ваши интерфейсы (3 массива).
Для реализации нашего класса сделаем 4 метода: 3 из которых будут формировать 3 целевых массива, а четвертый - читать файл в двухмерный исходный массив. Конструктор будет принимать имя файла, вызывать указанные приватные методы, инициализируя поля (3 нужных нам массива). ну и, разумеется, геттеры для того, чтобы получит наши массивы. посему реализация выглядит так:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Matrix {

    private final Double [] shops;
    private final Double [] buyers;
    private final Double [][] prices;

    public Matrix(String fileName) throws IOException {
        final Double[][] sourceArray = readFile(fileName);
        this.shops = createShops(sourceArray);
        this.buyers = createBuyers(sourceArray);
        this.prices = createPrices(sourceArray);
    }

    private Double[][] readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            return stream
                    .map(i -> Arrays.stream(i.split(" "))
                        .peek(String::trim)
                        .map(Double::valueOf)
                        .toArray(Double[]::new))
                    .toArray(Double[][]::new);
        }
    }

    private Double[] createBuyers (Double[][] sourceArray) {
        return Arrays.copyOf(sourceArray[sourceArray.length - 1], sourceArray[sourceArray.length - 1].length);
    }

    private Double[] createShops (Double[][] sourceArray) {
            final List<Double> buyers = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < sourceArray.length-1; i++) {
                if (sourceArray[0].length==sourceArray[i].length) 
                    buyers.add(sourceArray[i][sourceArray[i].length-1]);
            }
            return buyers.toArray(new Double[buyers.size()]);
    }

    private Double[][] createPrices(Double[][] sourceArray) {
        final Double[][] distArray = new Double[sourceArray.length - 1][sourceArray[0].length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceArray.length - 1; i++) 
            System.arraycopy(sourceArray[i], 0, distArray[i], 0, sourceArray[i].length - 1);
        return distArray;
    }

    public Double[] getShops() {
        return shops;
    }

    public Double[] getBuyers() {
        return buyers;
    }

    public Double[][] getPrices() {
        return prices;
    }

}
```

P.S. хорошенько подумайте переде тем, как считать деньги в double, это совсем треш (никогда так не делайте на реальных проектах, только лонг).

Используем класс так:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix("ex3.txt");
        System.out.println("************************************************************");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix.getShops()));
        System.out.println(matrix.getShops().length);
        System.out.println("************************************************************");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix.getBuyers()));
        System.out.println(matrix.getBuyers().length);
        System.out.println("************************************************************");
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString((matrix.getPrices())));
        System.out.println("************************************************************");

    }
}
```

Comment: О каких реальных проектах идет речь? Это скорее курсовая "Решение транспортной задачи на JAVA" никто и никогда не будет этим пользоваться

Comment: @JVic это понятно, этот код умрет раньше, чем будет написан, поэтому я и не пытался это исправить, а на будущее предупредить не помешает.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Сейчас сяду разбираться в Вашем коде

Comment: @Annya не за что. если возникнут вопросы - задавайте.

Comment: @Дмитрий, подскажите пожалуйста , как можно узнать размер shops и buyers? При  shops.length() возникнет исключение

Comment: @Annya а у вас не может быть такого вызова в принципе. знаете, что такое инкапсуляция? поле shops приватное, это значит, что доступ к нему есть только в пределах класса, тогда возникает справделивый вопрос, как вы вызываете shops.length, не имея к нему доступа? вы не должны лезть в этот класс. а для доступа к  shops у вас есть геттер. вызов будет выглядеть так matrix.getShops().length. и последнее - shops.length()  - некорректный вызов, скобки здесь не нужны

Comment: @Annya откорректировал ответ, добавил примеры использования

Comment: @Дмитрий, спасибо большое за помощь, этому мало где учат.. Подскажите, а если я хочу добавить возможность считывать для массивов, у которых разное количество магазинов и покупателей. Можно ли немного изменить Ваш код для этого? Например покупатели (1,2,3,4), а производители (1,2,3)

Comment: @Annya не совсем понятен вопрос. можете в вопросе добавить пример того, как будет выглядеть массив данных?

Comment: @Дмитрий, добавила пример в задание

Comment: @Annya в этом случае надо понимать, к чему относится 40 (число, расположенное в правом нижнем углу). по описанному вами условию его вообще не должно быть, потому что мы вычитываем последнюю строку и последний столбец, а это число одновременно относится и к строке и к столбцу. так к чему мы относим последнее число?

Comment: @Дмитрий, относим к покупателям. я добавлю картинку, чтобы было виднее

Comment: @Annya вы в комментарии писали наоборот: последний столбец матрицы (14 10 15) -- всегда покупатели, последняя строка (10 15 12) -- всегда магазины. а теперь в вопрос добавили :  Последняя строка -- всегда покупатели, и считываться должна полностью. где покупатели? в последнем столбце или последней строке?

Comment: @Annya я исправил код в соответствии с картинками (последняя строка читается всегда полностью). протестируйте.

Comment: @Дмитрий, работает, спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли! Пойду разбираться с кодом

Comment: @Annya пробуйте и спрашивайте, если что-то непонятно, потому как мне кажется, что вы неверно поняли, что я имел в виду под инкапсуляцией в данном случае. это не означает, что вы не можете менять логику класса, который я написал, это значит(исходя из вашего описания), что вы не должны реализовывать дополнительную логику , не свойственному этому классу, либо открывать доступ к полям класса извне. посмотрите на досуге (это , пожалуй, самая базовая лекция из всех, которые я читал, должно быть полезно) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ARd-Hsq79mSSqhFl14m83-n7qCKcjiyN/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Приведу решение в процедурном стиле.

```
int m = 3; // число строк матрицы затрат (число покупателей)
int n = 4; // число столбцов матрицы затрат (число магазинов)
double[][] c = new double[m][n];
double[] a = new double[m];
double[] b = new double[n];
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("ex3.txt"));
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    c[i][j] = sc.nextDouble();
  }
  a[i] = sc.nextDouble();
}
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
  b[j] = sc.nextDouble();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(c));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

Comment: Было бы у нас еще указано в файле/ еще где-то количество строк/столбцов.. Но спасибо большое, сейчас сяду разбираться